# Automatic list partitioning

Tags: oracle, varchar, database-partitioning

I'm using Oracle 11g.

I have large table that I want to add partitions. My partition (and subpartition) key column is of `VARCHAR2` type.

I know that there is an `INTERVAL RANGE PARTITION` that can be auto-created but I need to do the same thing with `list partition`. Is there a way to do that with `VARCHAR2` type (which doesn't represent any date).

Example:

```
create table t1 (name varchar2(30), company varchar2(10), value number);
```

I want that for every new `name` there will be a new partition. Is there a way to do that without writing specific PL/SQL code that will check if a new partition is needed and will do the creation? Maybe with some pattern or something...

Comment: Unfortunately you need to upgrade. Automatic list partitioning was introduced with Oracle 12c R2. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/automatic-list-partitioning-12cr2)

Answer (score 3):

Automatic list partitioning was [added in 12.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/12-things-developers-will-love-about-oracle-database-12c-release-2#auto-list-partition). So you need to upgrade to do this.

In the meantime, you can create a catch-all, default partition. Then split new values out as needed:

```
create table t (
  c1 int
) partition by list ( c1 ) (
  partition pdef values ( default ) 
);

select partition_name, high_value 
from   user_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME   HIGH_VALUE   
PDEF             default     

insert into t values ( 1 );
insert into t values ( 2 );

alter table t 
  split partition pdef
  values ( 1 ) into ( 
    partition p1, partition pdef 
  );

alter table t 
  split partition pdef
  values ( 2 ) into ( 
    partition p2, partition pdef 
  );

select partition_name, high_value 
from   user_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME   HIGH_VALUE   
P1               1            
P2               2            
PDEF             default
```

When you get to 12.2, you can switch it to auto-list. But you need to drop the default partition first!

```
alter table t set partitioning automatic;

ORA-14852: SET [SUB]PARTITIONING AUTOMATIC is not legal on this table.

alter table t drop partition pdef;

alter table t set partitioning automatic;

insert into t values ( 3 );

select partition_name, high_value 
from   user_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME   HIGH_VALUE   
P1               1            
P2               2            
SYS_P5201        3
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good idea. Is there a problem of access to the data of the default partition at the time of split?

Comment: @user2671057 you mean querying it while the auto-split happens? I'm not aware of any issues; but I haven't tested extensively.

Comment: I mean querying the default partition in 11g version - in time of alter table split partition. with my tests it will cause to object- no-longer-exists exception. It also raise if the query is on the whole table... this is my problem.